# Maximal Ideals of the Wiener Algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, ideals

I'm wondering why the maximal ideals of the Wiener algebra $\mathcal{W}$ are of the form $\{M_z:z\in \mathbb{T}\}$ where $M_z=\{f\in \mathcal{W}\; |\; f(z)=0\}$.

Given that the Wiener algebra is a commutative Banach algebra we have to find a continuous linear functional $\phi$ on $\mathcal{W}$ such that $\ker(\phi) = M_z$, right? But I have no idea how  we do this?

By continuous linear functional in this context we mean a homomorphism of $\mathcal{A}$ into $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: A superficial look at the information in the wiki on Wiener's theorem makes this look like a nontrivial result. Out of curiosity, is a linear functional in this context an algebra homomorphism into the underlying field? If it's just a vector space linear functional, its kernel might not be a ring ideal...

Comment: You're absolutely right, you really do need an algebra homomorphism $\mathcal{A} \to \mathbb{C}$, and not a linear functional.

Comment: I believe a homorphism in this context is called a continuous linear functional or a character?

Comment: They're also called characters, yes, and while they are, in particular, continuous linear functionals, you never call them that, because the word "functional" doesn't imply anything about behaviour with respect to the algebra structure.

In any event, though, if you look up proofs of Gelfand--Naimark duality for commutative unital $C^\ast$-algebras, I suspect you'd be able to get at least some ideas about how to tackle the maximum spectrum of $\mathcal{W}$.

Comment: *continuous multiplicative linear functional I mean. Thanks for your advice.